# Scale bitmap and set as wallpaper - height gets messy

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to scale a bitmap to screen size and set it as wallpaper, but I've noticed on some devices(where the screen is a bit wider) the wallpaper is a little messy in height. Can someone help me scale the image in right way?

Here is my code:

```
int widthPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getWidth();
                int heightPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getHeight();
                // bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, widthPx, heightPx,
                // true);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) background
                        .getDrawable();

                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                try {
                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            bitmap,
                            myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth(),
                            myWallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight(),
                            true);
                    myWallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                    myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(widthPx,
                            heightPx);
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                    Toast.makeText(BackgroundPreview.this,
                            getString(R.string.wallpaper_set),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(BackgroundPreview.this,
                            getString(R.string.error_setting_wallpaper),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: `a little messy in height ` what does it means ?

Comment: @ben75 if a device has a little wider screen, the image is little squized in the height - because it has more wider surface

Comment: And what result do you expect ? (what do you mean by "right way" ?)

Comment: @ben75 a properly scaled image according to the screen

Comment: what means properly scaled ? keeping aspect ratio with black border ? keeping aspect ratio without black border ? something else ?

Comment: @ben75 keeping aspect ratio without black border - can u provide me a solution?